# Fast percentile in C++

Tags: c++, performance, percentile

My program calculates a Monte Carlo simulation for the value-at-risk metric. To simplify as much as possible, I have:

```
1/ simulated daily cashflows
2/ to get a sample of a possible 1-year cashflow, 
   I need to draw 365 random daily cashflows and sum them
```

Hence, the daily cashflows are an empirically given distrobution function to be sampled 365 times. For this, I

```
 1/ sort the daily cashflows into an array called *this->distro*
 2/ calculate 365 percentiles corresponding to random probabilities
```

I need to do this simulation of a yearly cashflow, say, 10K times to get a population of simulated yearly cashflows to work with. Having the distribution function of daily cashflows prepared, I do the sampling like...

```
for ( unsigned int idxSim = 0; idxSim < _g.xSimulationCount; idxSim++ )
{
    generatedVal = 0.0;
    for ( register unsigned int idxDay = 0; idxDay < 365; idxDay ++ )
    {
        prob = (FLT_TYPE)fastrand();         // prob [0,1]
        dIdx = prob * dMaxDistroIndex;       // scale prob to distro function size
                                             // to get an index into distro array
        _floor = ((FLT_TYPE)(long)dIdx);     // fast version of floor
        _ceil  = _floor + 1.0f;              // 'fast' ceil:)
        iIdx1  = (unsigned int)( _floor );
        iIdx2  = iIdx1 + 1;

        // interpolation per se
        generatedVal += this->distro[iIdx1]*(_ceil - dIdx  );
        generatedVal += this->distro[iIdx2]*(dIdx  - _floor);
    }
    this->yearlyCashflows[idxSim] = generatedVal ;
}
```

The code inside of both `for` cycles does linear interpolation. If, say USD 1000 corresponds to prob=0.01, USD 10000 corresponds to prob=0.1 then if I don't have an empipirical number for p=0.05 I want to get USD 5000 by interpolation.

The question: this code runs correctly, though the profiler says that the program spends cca 60% of its runtime on the interpolation per se. So my question is, how can I make this task faster? Sample runtimes reported by VTune for specific lines are as follows:

```
prob = (FLT_TYPE)fastrand();         //  0.727s
dIdx = prob * dMaxDistroIndex;       //  1.435s
_floor = ((FLT_TYPE)(long)dIdx);     //  0.718s
_ceil  = _floor + 1.0f;              //    -

iIdx1  = (unsigned int)( _floor );   // 4.949s
iIdx2  = iIdx1 + 1;                  //    -

// interpolation per se
generatedVal += this->distro[iIdx1]*(_ceil - dIdx  );  //    -
generatedVal += this->distro[iIdx2]*(dIdx  - _floor);  // 12.704s
```

Dashes mean the profiler reports no runtimes for those lines.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.
Daniel

**EDIT:**
Both c.fogelklou and MSalters have pointed out great enhancements. The best code in line with what c.fogelklou said is

```
converter = distroDimension / (FLT_TYPE)(RAND_MAX + 1)
for ( unsigned int idxSim = 0; idxSim < _g.xSimulationCount; idxSim++ )
{
    generatedVal = 0.0;
    for ( register unsigned int idxDay = 0; idxDay < 365; idxDay ++ )
    {
        dIdx  = (FLT_TYPE)fastrand() * converter;
        iIdx1 = (unsigned long)dIdx);
        _floor = (FLT_TYPE)iIdx1;
        generatedVal += this->distro[iIdx1] + this->diffs[iIdx1] *(dIdx  - _floor);
    }
}
```

and the best I have along MSalter's lines is

```
normalizer = 1.0/(FLT_TYPE)(RAND_MAX + 1);
for ( unsigned int idxSim = 0; idxSim < _g.xSimulationCount; idxSim++ )
{
    generatedVal = 0.0;
    for ( register unsigned int idxDay = 0; idxDay < 365; idxDay ++ )
    {
        dIdx  = (FLT_TYPE)fastrand()* normalizer ;
        iIdx1 = fastrand() % _g.xDayCount;
        generatedVal += this->distro[iIdx1];
        generatedVal += this->diffs[iIdx1]*dIdx;
    }
}
```

The second code is approx. 30 percent faster. Now, of 95s of total runtime, the last line consumes 68s. The last but one line consumes only 3.2s hence the double*double multiplication must be the devil. I thought of SSE - saving the last three operands into an array and then carry out a vector multiplication of this->diffs[i]*dIdx[i] and add this to this->distro[i] but this code ran 50 percent slower. Hence, I think I hit the wall.

Many thanks to all.
D.

Comment: do you have an explanation why your last line takes so much time where as the line before that has no reported time? They should take exactly the same time except for the compiler mixing them into one or something like this.

Comment: Philipp: I'm just reposting what VTune tells me. I bet the real effect is 6.3s for each line separately.

Comment: For your title question (!= your fastrand question), see "Single-pass estimation of quantiles" in [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html?pg=435) pages 435-438, with plots and c++ code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a proposal for a small optimization, removing the need for ceil, two casts, and one of the multiplies.  If you are running on a fixed point processor, that would explain why the multiplies and casts between float and int are taking so long.  In that case, try using fixed point optimizations or turning on floating point in your compiler if the CPU supports it!

```
for ( unsigned int idxSim = 0; idxSim < _g.xSimulationCount; idxSim++ )
{
    generatedVal = 0.0;
    for ( register unsigned int idxDay = 0; idxDay < 365; idxDay ++ )
    {
        prob = (FLT_TYPE)fastrand();         // prob [0,1]
        dIdx = prob * dMaxDistroIndex;       // scale prob to distro function size
                                             // to get an index into distro array
        iIdx1  = (long)dIdx;
        _floor = (FLT_TYPE)iIdx1;     // fast version of floor
        iIdx2  = iIdx1 + 1;

        // interpolation per se
        {
           const FLT_TYPE diff = this->distro[iIdx2] - this->distro[iIdx1];
           const FLT_TYPE interp = this->distro[iIdx1] + diff * (dIdx - _floor);
           generatedVal += interp;
        }
    }
    this->yearlyCashflows[idxSim] = generatedVal ;
}
```

Comment: Hi c.fogelklou, thanks a lot. Im not that experienced in such low level  programming, so please forgive my stupid question: what is a fixed point processor? At home, Im running this on i7 860, at work on Athlon X2. 

Some other minor improvements can be gained by e.g. `iIdx2 = (iIdx1 = ((long)dIdx) + 1)` etc. As for the const FLT_TYPE diff, that is awesome. These diffs can be precalculated, that should save some cycles too.

Comment: If you're running on an I7, don't worry about it... You definitely have floating point support.  Fixed point optimizations would be replacing floating point multiplies and divides by integer multiplies and divides.  You would do this by, for example, multiplying your float with range -1..1 by say 32768, working with it as an integer with range -32768 to 32768.  It makes the code much more complicated, though, so be glad it's not necessary!

Comment: This is indeed the correct idea; using `diff` saves you a floating-point multiply.

Comment: Hi c.fogelklou, the removal of the extra (unnecessary) conversion took away 2.5s of 10.7s which is a huge gain. Precalculating the diffs and some minor changes cut off another time to a 6.1s. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to fix `fastrand`. Floating-point code isn't the fastest in the world, but what is especially slow is the switching between floating point and integer code. Since you need an integer index, use an integer random function.

It may even be advantageous to pre-generate all 365 random values in a loop. Since you need only `log2(dMaxDistroIndex)` bits of randomness per value, you may be able to reduce the number of RNG calls.

You would subsequently pick a random number between 0 and 1 for the interpolation fraction.

Comment: My code is 
`normalizer = 1.0/(FLT_TYPE)(RAND_MAX+1); dIdx  = (FLT_TYPE)fastrand()* normalizer ;
iIdx1 = fastrand() % _distroDimension;
generatedVal += this->distro[iIdx1] + this->diffs[iIdx1]*dIdx` and now the last operation takes the most time, obviously. In comparison to c.fogelklou's solution, I saved one double minus double operation and added one uint modulo. The fastrand() function is simple and fast from http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-random-number-generator-on-the-intel-pentiumr-4-processor so no gains to be gotten from that. Is this what you meant? Many thanks.