# Fast percentile in C++ - speed more important than precision

Tags: c++, performance

This is a follow-up to [Fast percentile in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890079/fast-percentile-in-c)

I have a sorted array of 365 daily cashflows (`xDailyCashflowsDistro`) which I randomly sample 365 times to get a generated yearly cashflow. Generating is carried out by

```
1/ picking a random probability in the [0,1] interval
2/ converting this probability to an index in the [0,364] interval
3/ determining what daily cashflow corresponds to this probability by using the index and some linear aproximation.
```

and summing 365 generated daily cashflows. Following the previously mentioned thread, my code precalculates the differences of sorted daily cashflows (`xDailyCashflowDiffs`) where

```
xDailyCashflowDiffs[i] = xDailyCashflowsDistro[i+1] - xDailyCashflowsDistro[i]
```

and thus the whole code looks like

```
double _dIdxConverter = ((double)(365 - 1)) / (double)(RAND_MAX - 1);

for (  unsigned int xIdx = 0; xIdx < _xCount; xIdx++ )
{
    double generatedVal = 0.0;
    for (  unsigned int xDayIdx = 0; xDayIdx < 365; xDayIdx ++ )
    {
         double dIdx    = (double)fastRand()* _dIdxConverter;       
         long   iIdx1   = (unsigned long)dIdx;                          
         double dFloor  = (double)iIdx1;                                

        generatedVal += xDailyCashflowsDistro[iIdx1] + xDailyCashflowDiffs[iIdx1] *(dIdx  - dFloor);
    }
    results.push_back(generatedVal) ;
}
```

`_xCount` (the number of simulations) is 1K+, usually 10K.

**The problem:**
  This simulation is being carried out 15M times (compared to 100K when the first thread was written) at the moment, and it takes ~10 minutes on a 3.4GHz machine. Due to the nature of problem, this 15M is unlikely to be significantly lowered in the future, only increased. Having used VTune Analyzer, I am being told that the last but one line (`generatedVal += ...`) generates 80% of runtime. And my question is why and how I can work with that.

**Things I have tried:**

1/ getting rid of the `(dIdx  - dFloor)` part to see whether double difference and multiplication is the main culprit - runtime dropped by a couple of percent

2/  declaring `xDailyCashflowsDistro` and `xDailyCashflowDiffs` as `__restict` so as to prevent the compiler thinking they are dependendent on each other - no change

3/ tried using 16 days (as opposed to 365) to see whether it is cache misses that drag my performance - not a slight change

4/ tried using floats as opposed to doubles - no change

5/ compiling with different /fp: - no change

6/ compiling as x64 - has effect on the double <-> ulong conversions, but the line in question is unaffected

What I am willing to sacrifice is resolution - I do not care whether the `generatedVal` is 100010.1 or 100020.0 at the end if the speed gain is substantial.

**EDIT:**
The daily/yearly cashflows are related to the whole portfolio. I could divide all daily cashflows by portflio size and would thus (at 99.99% confidence level) ensure that daily cashflows/pflio_size will not reach out of the [-1000,+1000] interval. In this case, though, I would need precision to the hundredths.

Comment: you are dealing with cash and you are not interested in precision ? What is this really about ? ah ? ... just kidding floating point math it's not good for money anyway ...

Comment: @user2485710: You wrote before I edited ... +-10 CZK divided by a big pflio size is zero difference.

Comment: If `speed is more important that precission`, then `result = 42;` should do it, it is pretty fast. Anyway, I would store  `xDailyCashflowsDistro[iIdx1]` and the other value in an scalar variable to avoid the lookups...

Comment: Keep in mind that at some point you have to **actually** buy hardware and start thinking in paralel processing.

Comment: @SJuan76: Interesting, two comments, both pointing out to the fact that I dont care about 50 US cents. As for paralel processing, I am looking at launching this way more than 15M times, so even at eight cores it could take days, unless I understand why this runs slow. Wouldnt a direct jump to paralelization be premature in this case and state of code?

Comment: Forget the "scalar variable" idea, I had missread `iIdx1` for `xIdx`. In relation to paralelization, it is up to you to compare the cost of the time you need to optimize the code with the cost of the HW.

Comment: I'm a little confused following the code.  Where is `xIdx` used?  Or are you just producing `xCount` random samplings?

Comment: BTW, do you get any speed up if you do `results.resize(_xCount)` outside the loop and use `results[xIdx]` inside the loop?  You might also consider adding an `assert(_xCount > 1000)` or similar ahead of the outer `for` loop if that is indeed true; it might talk the compiler into unrolling the outer loop.  The biggest issue is that you can't really vectorize this code, though.

Comment: Have you considered dropping the interpolation in the loop in favor of a bigger lookup table? E.g. fill a lookup table of 365*10 entries and simply sum `distro[rand()%3650]` N times.

Comment: And are you sure the interpolation step adds real substance to your analysis in the first place? Can't it be replaced by a minor statistical correction on the end result, after simply summing `distro[rand()%365]`?

Comment: @JoeZ: `xIdx` is just a simulation index. In the real code (which was abbreviated before putting here), the vector is a preallocated array, so no gains to be realized there.

Comment: @mvds: Not yet, but I will try that and post the results. What minor statistical correction do you have in mind specifically?

Comment: I think you can view this algorithm as having 2 parts with different statistics. The main part, summing the day totals, is the part that adds substance to your analysis, and depends heavily on your actual percentile distribution. The interpolation part sums random values with a range that only slightly depends on the percentile distribution. This last part possibly has a clean gaussian distribution (you could test for that). If that is indeed the case, you can replace the 365 interpolations by a value taken from this gaussion.

Comment: Cont'd: This gaussian might have an average value of approx. `(distro[364]-distro[0])/365/2` (i.e. half the average step) for a reasonably flat distribution, and a small standard deviation, since you're summing 365 uniformly distributed numbers. Depending on whatever you do with the results of this analysis, you might consider ignoring the interpolation part, now you can quantify its actual impact on the end result. PS. I'm not a statistician, don't blame me if this doesn't make sense!

Comment: @mvds: That seems to make sense to me too. I will fiddle with this over the next week and will be back with a result!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could turn your piecewise linear function into a piecewise-linear "histogram" of its values.  The number you're sampling appears to be the sum of 365 samples from that histogram.  What you're doing is a not-particularly-fast way to sample from the sum of 365 samples from that histogram.

You might try computing a Fourier (or wavelet or similar) transform, keeping only the first few terms, raising it to the 365th power, and computing the inverse transform.  You won't get a probability distribution in the end, but there shouldn't be "too much" mass below 0 or above 1 and the total mass shouldn't be "too different" from 1 with this technique.  (I don't know what your data looks like; this technique may well be unworkable for good mathematical reasons.)